# Java converting 1d2h3m into milliseconds

Tags: java

I'm attempting to write a program where I can insert a string such as

```
5d2h7m (5 days 2 hours 7 minutes)
```

and it will take

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

and add the 5 days 2 hours and 7 minutes to get a new value, which I then save. Later when needed I can check the saved time to see if it has passed.

I'm confused on how to convert 5 days 2 hours and 7 minutes into milliseconds.

Is there a generic Java method for this that I'm missing?

Edit: I'm trying to convert the string into milliseconds, not the other way around.

Comment: you have to post code to get help, posting requirements and showing no attempt/effort is just asking others to do your work for free.

Comment: You can use the new [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package for this. Look at Duration and Period.

Comment: Then just do the opposite of the duplicate, it is that simple, you have to show some effort to get help with existing code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to solve my problem:
(timeArgs is a String[] that was split up from the string in the problem)

```
        long days = 0;
        long hours = 0;
        long minutes = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < timeArgs.length; x++) {
                if (timeArgs[x].contains("d")) {
                    days = Long.parseLong(timeArgs[x].replace("d", ""));
                    break;
                } else if (timeArgs[x].contains("h")) {
                    hours = Long.parseLong(timeArgs[x].replace("h", ""));
                    break;
                } else if (timeArgs[x].contains("m")) {
                    minutes = Long.parseLong(timeArgs[x].replace("m", ""));
                    break;
                }
            }

        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(days) + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours) + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes); // Current time plus other values
        System.out.print("millis is " + millis);
```

Comment: *"timeArgs is a String[] that was split up from the string in the problem"* How? Show that part. Also, remove unnecessary indentation. Congrats on your first answer!

Comment: Probably worth mentioning: The use of `TimeUnit` is a convenience. In reality, the number of milliseconds in a day is variable (DST, leap seconds), but as used above it's a constant: `1000L * 60 * 60 * 24`. And the same for the others. Still, `TimeUnit` is there, and reusing it avoids embarrassing bugs like missing out one of the `* 60` or some such.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a generic Java method for this that I'm missing?

No, not in the JDK. You have to parse the string yourself, probably using [`java.util.regex`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html), then do the appropriate multiplication and addition yourself.

Comment: I've parsed the string, that part was easy. It's the time -> milliseconds I'm having issues finding a method for.